# How to open popup window in Struts 2

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2, popup, struts2-jquery

I am trying to open a new window on clicking a link. I am doing it using the below code in Struts 2. I also need to pass the value of filed `bankAccountNumber`.

```xml
   ....
    <tr>
     <td align="center" width="16%">More Details 
       <a href='<s:url action='getEmployeeMoredetails' escapeAmp="false" >
        <s:param name='bankAccountNumber' value='bankAccountNumber' />
        </s:url>' target="_blank">
       <font size="2" color="BLUE"><b>More Details</b></font>
      </a>
     </td>
    </tr>
   ....
```

Now the above code is working fine and its opening the page in a separate window and it also passes the value of the field. But I want to open it in a pop up window. I am not sure how to do this using `window.open()` method in Struts to and also pass the value. Is there is any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure what you want is a popup ? That is a really old technology. Check out modal overlays, iframes, etc... to see if they fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate code is to use [JQuery UI dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) wrapped with the struts2-jquery code library. The [Dialog](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/DialogTag) widget renders a HTML Dialog with remote content.

```jsp
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<html>
  <head>
    <sj:head jqueryui="true"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <s:url var="remoteurl" action="getEmployeeMoredetails" escapeAmp="false"><s:param name='bankAccountNumber' value='bankAccountNumber' /></s:url>
    <sj:dialog id="mydialog" href="%{remoteurl}" title="More Details" autoOpen="false"/>
   <sj:a openDialog="mydialog">More Details</sj:a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Roman C for your reply. I tried this out, but its not working for me